# Can't run Artisan::call('migrate')

Tags: php, laravel, centos6, vps, laravel-artisan

I have a problem with Laravel 5.3 on Apache server hosted on CentOS, VPS.
When I try to call `Artisan::call('migrate')`, I'm get in die dump 0 and application not fire migrate. I was try that on vagrant and wamp in local and everything work fine and artisan command fires.

What I have to check on server, what package or module?

Comment: What happens if you run the artisan command via command line: `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: Command fires and do database migrate.

Comment: Does it ask you to confirm migration? i.e. `are you sure you want to migrate?`

Comment: Yes, I want to migrate because I do that method on app start. I was solved the problem with external api route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found the solution using external api route. I was do that on server and I can't run that command from main